# Dynamic Tab bar BG color

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

I need to make a tabbar that dynamically changes color, regarding which tab is chosen. So at the root pages it works fine, i have this in my tabbar xaml.cs:

```
public partial class BottomTabNavigation : TabbedPage
{
    public BottomTabNavigation() => InitializeComponent();

    private async void TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var navigationPage = CurrentPage as NavigationPage;
        var currentPage = navigationPage.CurrentPage;

        if (currentPage.GetType() == typeof(FrontPage) || currentPage.GetType() == typeof(HerdList))
        {
            Tabbar.BarTextColor = Color.White;
            Tabbar.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0c597a");
            Tabbar.SelectedTabColor = Color.FromHex("#004864");
            Tabbar.UnselectedTabColor = Color.White;
        }
        else 
        {
            Tabbar.BarTextColor = Color.Black;
            Tabbar.BarBackgroundColor = Color.White;
            Tabbar.SelectedTabColor = Color.FromHex("#004864");
            Tabbar.UnselectedTabColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

So the issue i'm facing is that when i've navigated to the HerdList tab, i can, via a list, open a new page, where the tabbar needs to change from blue BG to white BG. This isn't picked up by the "TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged", while i don't change tab, just page.

How can I achieve this?

***EDIT***

BottomTabNavigation.xaml:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
        x:Class="ChrApp.Views.Tab.BottomTabNavigation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChrApp.Views"
        xmlns:Menu="clr-namespace:ChrApp.Views.Menu"
        xmlns:Letter="clr-namespace:ChrApp.Views.Letter"
        x:Name="Tabbar"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        xmlns:CustomRenderer="clr-namespace:ChrApp.CustomRenderer"
        CurrentPageChanged="TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
         xmlns:Resources="clr-namespace:ChrApp.Resources"
        >
<NavigationPage 
    Title="{Resources:Translate Front_Page}"
                >
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:FrontPage/>
    </x:Arguments>
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="{x:Static CustomRenderer:Icon.House}"/>
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
</NavigationPage>

<NavigationPage 
    Title="{Resources:Translate Herd}"
                >
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:HerdList/>
    </x:Arguments>
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="{x:Static CustomRenderer:Icon.Pig}"/>
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
</NavigationPage>

<NavigationPage 
    Title="{Resources:Translate More}"
                >
    <x:Arguments>
        <Menu:MenuPage/>
    </x:Arguments>
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="{x:Static CustomRenderer:Icon.Menu}"/>
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
</NavigationPage>
```

I've noticed that the **TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged** is triggered. But when i navigate, by choosing a element in the list, it says that the currentpage is **FrontPage** and not **HerdDetails** for some reason.

Comment: I could us the `this.CurrentPage` to change the bar color when you change the specific tabs. https://imgur.com/yKZawD5 Could you provide more details about what you did when you navigate to the HerdList tab?

Comment: Thanks for the response! :)
Im using the Prism libary, so i use the `NavigationService`, and the method within called `SelectTabAsync`. I've also implemented the `IActiveAware` on the the root pages viewmodels(FrontPage, HerdList and More) for the tabs, to check when the tab is navigated to. 
Hope that that was enough details :)
BTW. Thanks for the screen recording, it's a bit flashy though :)